# how can i point my bastion host ec2 which don't have any public ip with godaddy domain?

Tags: devops

I have a bastion host ec2 ,which don't have any public IP address ,but i have one application load balancer which is integrated with private EC2 ,but when I added CNAME(ALB DNS Record) record with host name WWW in my Godaddy DNS records So my website works only with https://www.example.com ,all other urls like -
https://example.com,
http://example.com do not work.

after that I had use the domain forwarding feature of godaddy but through this feature I can forward only one url like- example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) but I want my all urls should work fine.
Do we resolve this issue by help of A record?

I added CNAME(ALB DNS Record) record with host name WWW in my Godaddy DNS records but my website works only with https://www.example.com .

I had use the domain forwarding feature of godaddy but through this feature I can forward only one url like- example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) .

Comment: You should be asking on [SF]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start using AWS Route53 to manage the DNS records, after that, you can create A record to point to the ALB. You would have to create a hosted zone for example.com, then copy the name servers of it and use update your Godaddy configuration to use AWS name servers. More information can be found here: https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2020/07/14/migrating-dns-services-aws.aspx